# Create a folder from a HTML form input via PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to create a PHP script that allows me to create a folder from an input value in an HTML form. This is what I tried so far:

HTML:

```
<form  action="cfolder.php">
<input  name="foldername" id="foldername" >

<input type="submit" value="upload" />
</form>
```

PHP i.e. cfolder.php

```
<?php

$subject = $_POST["foldername"] = $foldername; 
mkdir($foldername, 0700);


?>
```

Unfortunately the folder is not being created. I tried other solutions but to no avail.

*The error it gives me is [11-Mar-2013 12:54:51] PHP Warning:  mkdir() [function.mkdir]: No such file or directory in /home5/../cfolder.php on line 4*

Comment: Did you see any error dumped or in log files?

Comment: Are there any errors in the logs? It may be a permission issue

Comment: You got the wrong assignment direction

Comment: Does your script have permission to create the folder?

Comment: May be you do not have permission to create a folder. please check.

Comment: I can create folders cos I use another script to create folders e.g. mkdir("uploads", 0700); and it works. The error I get is _The error it gives me is [11-Mar-2013 12:54:51] PHP Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: No such file or directory in /home5/../cfolder.php on line 4_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `$_POST` and send the form input via GET - this couldn't work. Use `$_GET` or set `method="POST"`

also you have to edit the assigment

```
$foldername = $_POST["foldername"];
```

Btw. keep sure, your are in the right directory and have the persmissions to create files

Comment: Thank you @Philipp it worked exactly how I wanted. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$subject = $_POST["foldername"] = $foldername;
```

will assign whatever value is in $foldername to both $_POST['foldername'] AND $subject.

If the var was blank to start with, you're errasing $subject and $_POST['foldername'];

Remember, in PHP the result of assignment is the value being assigned.

e.g.

```
$foo = $bar = $baz = 7;
```

sets all three variables to `7`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 $subject = $foldername = $_POST["foldername"]; 
 mkdir($foldername, 0700);
?>
```

The variables get evaluated from right to left. The result of an assignment is the value being assigned. In your example you are setting both $subject and  $_POST["foldername"] to $foldername, which is unset.